# Use URLFetch in init.m

Tags: initialization, web-access

I'm not able to use `URLFetch` in my `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/Init.m` as it always returns `ImportString[Null, Text, CharacterEncoding -> "ISO8859-1"]`.

Here is my test code, which works in a Notebook, but runs forever in the init file:

```
ip = $Failed;

While[ip == $Failed,
     ip = Quiet@Check[URLFetch@"http://tyilo.com/ip/", $Failed]
];
MessageDialog[ip];
```

The reason I would like to use `URLFetch` in my init script is that I have distributed it to a couple of friends and I would like to make it automatically update.
Everything except the `URLFetch` part of the auto-update script works, so it would be nice to be able to finish this feature.

If you could make it run asynchronously after Mathematica has fully started up, that would be fine too.

Comment: There are other things which do not work at this stage of the initialization. I remember that pattern matching of string didn't work correctly either. We had a discussion about this here and when I remember correctly, we came to the conclusion that it has something to do with JLink which is not functional at this stage.

Comment: You could consider putting the update in `$Epilog` instead.  (I haven't tried it and it should be noted that it's invoked when returning from a `Dialog` as well, which may not be a good thing in this case.)  Be careful about using things like `MessageDialog`, they're not command line friendly.

Comment: @halirutan It seems ``Needs["JLink`"]; JLink`InstallJava[]`` does work in init.m, but it doesn't fix URLFetch.

Comment: @Szabolcs I now remember: When I had the first version of the automcompletion, which only worked in version 9.0.0, I had the code in `init.m`. Back then, the check for the OS like `If[StringMatchQ[$SystemID,"Linux-*"],..` did not work. I thought we (I mean literaly, you and me) had spoken about it.

Comment: The conclusion was that `StringMatchQ` uses some java stuff for the regex matching.

Comment: @Szabolcs Putting a function in `$Epilog` doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a scheduled task I made the following workaround:

```
Module[{t},
    t = CreateScheduledTask[
        "initFileScheduledTask";
        If[URLFetch@"http://example.org/" =!= Null,
            t = Select[ScheduledTasks[],
                StringMatchQ[ToString@#[[2]], StartOfString ~~ "initFileScheduledTask" ~~ ___] &
            ];
            RemoveScheduledTask @ t;
            ip = Quiet@Check[URLFetch@"http://tyilo.com/ip/", $Failed];
            MessageDialog @ ip;
        ],
        1
    ];
    StartScheduledTask @ t;
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The code from the original post works correctly when placed in `init.m` as of version 11.2.0.

For more details, see the following [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111683/145).