# Handling Kernel start. What is a full initialization stack and what place the Autoload has there?

Tags: kernel, kernel-startup, system

According to: [**tutorial/WolframSystemSessions**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemSessions.html)

> #### Initialization
>
> On startup, the Wolfram Language kernel does the following:
>
> - Performs license management operations.
> - Runs Wolfram Language commands specified in any -run options passed to the kernel executable.
> - Runs the Wolfram Language commands in the systemwide initialization file `$BaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`.
> - Runs the Wolfram Language commands in the user-specific initialization file `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`.
> - Loads `init.m` and `Kernel/init.m` files in Autoload directories.
> - Begins running the main loop.

So I'd say that packages in Autoload have a freedom to do everything since everything should be already loaded. Yet this example fails:

```
dir = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Autoload", "Fetch", "Kernel"}];

CreateDirectory[dir, CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True]

SetDirectory @ dir;

Export[
 "init.m",
 "Print @ StringTake[URLFetch[\"www.wolfram.com\"], 300]; ", 
 "Text"]
```

Now quit the Kernel and evaluate something. I only get messages:

> URLFetch::invhttp: Couldn't resolve proxy name.
>
> StringTake[$Failed, 300]
>
> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level.
>
> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level.
>
> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[False] returned to top level.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Throw::nocatch
>        will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> Break::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[].

While normally this procedure works `StringTake[URLFetch["www.wolfram.com"], 300]`.

**Question** What's the problem? What more do we need to know about the Initialization stack? Are there any workarounds?

Currently I'm just setting procedure via `ScheduledTask` to fire 2 seconds later. But that's just silly.

This is not a question about `URLFetch` (yet good to know this specific problem) but about things I have to know to not be surprised next time.

Comment: The basic problem, which is not so easy to fix, is that the kernel initialization code has protection against aborts. Since `Throw`/`Catch` are implemented internally using this (C code level) abort machinery, they are not functional during initialization, so running any code using them is problematic. See also [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84539/possible-bug-of-loading-package-mathematica-10-1).

Comment: If you're using Windows, you might want to take a look at [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).

Comment: @ilian so `URLFetch::invhttp: Couldn't resolve proxy name.` is caused somehow by the Catch/Throw issue you are talking about or is there something more?

Comment: Yes, that is the cause.

Comment: I'd give a bounty for this if questions could get bounties.

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6553/12), you'll find most things in `sysinit.m`

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, missed that somehow

Comment: @Kuba I just edited that post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**

Leaving my original answer below for historical purposes, however it only applies up until version 11.1.1.

As of version 11.2.0, the kernel startup initialization has been overhauled and this example (as well as others) now works correctly: placing the `URLFetch` call in `init.m` does result in an output like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="homepage">
<head>

<!-- begin framework head en -->

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/b
```

This improvement was motivated in part by the new [Persistence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SettingPersistentValues.html) & [Initialization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/InitializationAndProvisioning.html) framework, and I recommend Roman Maeder's [presentation](http://wac.36f4.edgecastcdn.net/0036F4/pub/www.wolfram.com/technology-conference/2017/RomanMaederPersistence.nb) from the 2017 Wolfram Technology Conference.

---

To make my comment into an answer,

> The basic problem, which is not so easy to fix, is that the kernel
>   initialization code has protection against aborts. Since `Throw`/`Catch`
>   are implemented internally using this (C code level) abort machinery,
>   they are not functional during initialization, so running any code
>   using them is problematic.

The `URLFetch` implementation does depend on `Catch` working correctly, as can be seen from

```
TracePrint[URLFetch["www.wolfram.com"], _Catch]
```

Some related questions are the following: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84539/possible-bug-of-loading-package-mathematica-10-1?lq=1), [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32917/use-urlfetch-in-init-m), [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626491/uncaught-throw-generated-by-jlink-or-usefrontend), [(4)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17164/stringmatchq-and-alternatives-throws-message-in-init-m).

Comment: Can User and or Base Autoload be excluded from the initialization code but done as soon as the latter is finished? Is this problem expected to be solved in near future?

Comment: Does this mean that a package that uses `Throw` or `Abort` in its initialization cannot be auto-loaded?

Comment: @Szabolcs It seems not, but you can put ``RunScheduledTask[Get @ "Package`Package`", {5}]`` in init.m or whatever procedure you have in addition to `Get`. Then it will be fine.